# Run respective function for each numpy element in column

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy

Is there a way to speed up calling various functions through certain elements of array? Here we would like to call a function for each element in 2nd column based on function number in 3rd column.

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([[12, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 4, 1, 0], [2, 8, 2, 0, 0], [6, 3, 5, 1, 0]])

a
[[12  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  1  4  1  0]
 [ 2  8  2  0  0]
 [ 6  3  5  1  0]]
```

For loop that is currently used becomes extremely slow when the number of rows grows up. With millions of row it escalates to dozen of minutes to complete.

```
for y in range(1, a.shape[0]+1):
    exec('func{}()'.format(a[y, 2]))

def func4():
    a[y, 1 ] = a[y, 1] + 2

 def func2():
    a[1, 1 ] = a[1, 1] + 1

def func5():
   return
```

Comment: For iteration like that a list of lists would be faster.  And a dctionary of the `func` rather than the `exec`.  You're not taking advantage of `numpy` whole-array methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
my_func=eval('['+",".join(["func{}".format(x) for x in range(1,5+1)])+']')
or
my_func=[func0,func1,func2,func3,func4,func5]

for y in range(1, a.shape[0]+1):
        my_func[a[y, 2]]()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have one function with multiple branches? It would avoid the string formatting and you can have it call other functions if you don't want to put all the logic into one function. Have you tried it and found the if checks are too slow?

This code shows how you could break it up by having a main function that accepts two arguments and either runs the appropriate code or calls a sub-function.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[12, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 4, 1, 0], [2, 8, 2, 0, 0], [6, 3, 5, 1, 0]])


def main_func(c2_val, c3_val):
    if c3_val == 0:
        print("called with col3 value of 0")
        # code for func you would call i.e.
        a[c3_val, 1] = a[c3_val, 1] + 2
    elif c3_val == 4:  # on if for each possible outcome
        # or have it call another function
        func4()
    # etc


def func4():
    print("called with col3 value of 4")


for row in a:
    print(row)
    main_func(row[1], row[2])
```

Note: If you're really worried about run time and certain values are more likely make sure to put them higher up so fewer if checks are required.